# Smarty Fetch is not loading anything into my variable

Tags: php-5.3, smarty3

I have a class that sets up my smarty instances:

```
class View {
    protected $templateEngine;
    protected $templateExtension = '.tpl';


    public function __construct(){
        global $ABS_PUBLIC_PATH;
        global $ABS_PUBLIC_URL;
        $this->templateEngine = new Smarty();
        $this->templateEngine->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
        $this->templateEngine->setTemplateDir($ABS_PUBLIC_PATH . '/templates/');
        $this->templateEngine->setCompileDir($ABS_PUBLIC_PATH . '/templates_c/');
        $this->templateEngine->assign('ABS_PUBLIC_URL', $ABS_PUBLIC_URL);       

        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
            $this->assign('session', $_SESSION);
        }
    }

    public function assign($key, $value){
        $this->templateEngine->assign($key, $value);
    }

    public function display($templateName){
         $this->templateEngine->display($templateName . $this->templateExtension);
    }

    public function fetch($templateName){
         $this->templateEngine->fetch($templateName . $this->templateExtension);
    }
}
```

Then in my functions, I use the class like this:

```
public function showMeSomething()
    {
        $view = new View();
        $view->assign('session', $_SESSION);
        $view->display('header');
        $view->display('index');
        $view->display('footer');
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to fetch some data into a variable, in order to send emails from my template files as well.  Unfortunately, this var_dumps below (both of them) output `NULL` - even though the template file referenced has a lot of HTML in it.  Furthermore, changing the word `fetch` to `display` below will correctly display the template file.  So, the problem certainly lies within the fetch command.  I'm not sure what to do to continue debugging.

```
function emailPrep($data,){
    $mailView = new View();

    $emailHTML = $mailView->fetch('myEmail');   
    var_dump($mailView->fetch("myEmail"));
    var_dump($emailHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must be

```
public function fetch($templateName){
     return $this->templateEngine->fetch($templateName . $this->templateExtension);
}
```